# Not counting empty list while counting total lists count in Python

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists out of which 1 is empty. I want to take count of lists in a list which are not empty.

For example:

```
 a = ['username', 'username', 'social']
 b = []
 c = ['username', 'instead', 'added']
```

Combining all the lists together:

```
combine = [a,b,c]
```

Counting the non-empty lists:

```
count = sum(x is not '' for x in combine)
```

When I am running the above code, I have getting 'count=3' but I want 'count=2'

Please help me how should this can be done.

Comment: Why did you think `[] == ''` for an empty list?

Comment: Okay, so in that case I don't want to take count of [] and take count of rest.

Comment: You should just be able to do `sum(map(bool, combine))` or `sum(bool(x) for x in combine)`

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it worked for me.

Comment: Here is an another try `len(list(filter(None, combine))`

Answer (score 2):

try

> count =sum(len(x)>0 for x in combine)